How to copy file to Webdav at Mac OS with python?
Here is my code to mount the drive:
process = subprocess.Popen(['osascript', '-e mount volume "https://webdav.yandex.ru:443" as user name "me@yandex.ru" with password "mypassword"'],
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.communicate()

It works OK, the drive is mounted.
Now I try to copy my files there:
print("starting...")
shutil.copy('/Users/me/Documents/sample_file.kdbx', '/Volumes/webdav.yandex.ru/Folder/')
print("finished")

But it doesn't work. Nothing happens, no error, starting is printed and finished is never shown.
What could be wrong here?
